# select() on a pipe in blocking mode returns EAGAIN

Tags: c++, c, linux, select, blocking

The [man pages for select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) do not list EAGAIN as possible error code for the select() function.

Can anyone explain in which cases the select() can produce EAGAIN error?

If I understand [select_tut man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut), EAGAIN can be produced by sending a signal to the process which is blocked waiting on blocked select(). Is this correct?

Since I am using select() in blocking mode with timeout, like this:

```
bool selectRepeat = true;
int res = 0;
timeval  selectTimeout( timeout );
while ( true == selectRepeat )
{
  res = ::select( fd.Get() + 1,
                  NULL,
                  &writeFdSet,
                  NULL,
                  &selectTimeout );
  selectRepeat = ( ( -1 == res ) && ( EINTR == errno ) );
}
```

should I just repeat the loop when the error number is EAGAIN?

Comment: Show us the code that sets up `writeFdSet`. I imagine it's bogus. Also, are you sure the return value is -1? If not, `errno` has nothing to do with `select` and was probably set by an earlier call.

Comment: @R The man pages for select_tut confused me, since it mention EAGAIN and select. The return of select is 0, and EAGAIN is set who knows where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select()` will not return `EAGAIN` under any circumstance.
It may, however, return `EINTR` if interrupted by a signal (This applies to most system calls).

`EAGAIN` (or `EWOULDBLOCK`) may be returned from `read`, `write`, `recv`, `send`, etc.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut Go to this link, and scroll down to "Select laws", where it says that the select() can return EAGAIN. I was also puzzled to get EAGAIN from select(), hence the question.

Comment: @VJo: That's just an ambiguity in the tutorial, it makes no sense for `select` to return `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

EAGAIN is technically not an error, but an indication that the operation terminated without completing, and you should...er...try it again. You will probably want to write logic to retry, but not infinitely. If that was safe, they would have done it themselves in the API.

If you are thinking that returing a silly non-error error code like that is kinda bad client interface design, you aren't the first. It turns out EAGAIN as an error code has a long interesting history in Unix. Among other things, it spawned the widely circulated essay on software design [The Rise of Worse-is-Better](http://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html). There's a couple of paragraphs in the middle that explain why Unix needs to return this sometimes. Yes, it does indeed have something to do with receiving interrupts during an I/O. They call it PC loser-ing.

Many credit this essay as one of the inspirations for Agile programming.

Comment: AFAIK, In the context of socket/file operations, `EAGAIN` always signifies that the operation can not be completed without blocking, while the fd has been configured as non-blocking. Well behaved software would not loop around the call that got `EAGAIN` but rather either `select`/`poll` for readiness, or not set the fd non-blocking in the first place. only `EINTR` is returned when interrupted by a signal.

Comment: @Hasturkun - That sounds more like `EWOULDBLOCK`

Comment: `EAGAIN` is not valid behavior for `select`. See http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html and note "If none of the selected descriptors are ready for the requested operation, the pselect() or select() function shall block until at least one of the requested operations becomes ready, until the timeout occurs, or until interrupted by a signal."

Comment: @R.. - That would certianly explain the confusion.

Comment: `EWOULDBLOCK` is a synonym for `EAGAIN`.