# signal() and ualarm() in conflict with select()

Tags: c, select, signals, alarm

I have a `select()` to update my UI every second and also to handle user actions from X11. Here's a snippet of this source code:

```C
XEvent e;
/* Input file descriptor */
fd_set in_fd;
/* Get the file descriptor of the link with X11 */
int dpy_fd = ConnectionNumber(disp->dpy);

while (!finish) {
  FD_ZERO(&in_fd);
  FD_SET(dpy_fd, &in_fd);

  if (select(dpy_fd+1, &in_fd, 0, 0, &tv)) {
    printf("Event Received!\n");
    XNextEvent(disp->dpy, &e);
    /* do something */
  }
  else {
    printf("Timer Fired!\n");
    /* do something else*/
  }
}
```

So far, everything's ok.

In parallel, I need to use an alarm to do another thing every 500 ms so I implemented this:

```C
static void timer_handler(int sig)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN); /* ignore this signal */
  printf("timer_handler\n");
  signal(SIGALRM, timer_handler); /* reinstall the handler */
}

int test_timer()
{
  printf("test_timer\n");

  signal(SIGALRM, timer_handler);
  ualarm(1, 500000); /* every 500 ms */

  return 0;
}
```

I get *timer_handler* in my console every 500 ms but it's like it consumes the event from `select()` because I don't have *Timer Fired!* anymore (no more update of the UI). If I press a key or move the mouse over the UI, I get *Event Received!* in the console and the alarm is still responding.

**Is `select()` using the *SIGALRM* signal? What am I doing wrong?** I just want to use `select()` to handle the UI and an alarm to call a method every 500 ms (this method multiplexes hardware performance counters).

Comment: Your symptoms are consistent with blocking in `XNextEvent()`, but we don't have [enough information to help you troubleshoot](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Another nice example on how **not testing function calls for error** could lead to quiet some irritation ... - the code misses to test whether `select()` failed. It returns `-1` on error.

Comment: OT: At least on Linux you need to reset the timer values (in `tv`) passed to `select()` during each iteration, as they might get modified by `select()` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGALRM` is triggering an `EINTR` error in `select(2)` call. You must check whether the system call is returning a timeout, a file descriptor event or an error (and which kind of error too):

```
while (!finish) {
    int s;

    FD_ZERO(&in_fd);
    FD_SET(dpy_fd, &in_fd);

    s = select(dpy_fd+1, &in_fd, 0, 0, &tv)
    if (s > 0) {
        printf("Event Received!\n");
        XNextEvent(disp->dpy, &e);
        /* do something */
    } else if (s == 0) {
        /* This is probably where we should break the loop or reset the
         * select(2) timeout, so... I chose to break it. If you don't
         * do something about it you're gonna end up in a busy wait. */
        break;
    } else {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            /* We've been interrupted by another signal, and it might be
             * because of the alarm(3) (using the SIGALRM) or any other
             * signal we have received externally. */
            continue;
        }
        perror("Select failed");
        /* Handle the error properly. */
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the idea behind this `timer_fired` flag?

Comment: Thanks Fernando. With your code I get the following error `Select failed: Interrupted system call` which I don't really understand. I also agree with alk, could you please give us more information about the flag solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the timer reason. I thought you wanted to do something in the while loop every time the timer was fired. Now I removed it.

Comment: EAGAIN?  From select(2)?  [Are you sure?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4193106/132382)

Comment: With your solution, it seems to work but only if the alarm value is less than the select value. If I set `ualarm(1,1000000)` (or `alarm(1)`) and `select(...)` to trigger every second, the alarm handler is never called.

Comment: That's because `ualarm(3)` must never be called with interval >= 1000000 and `alarm(1)` must be rescheduled in the handler every time it is called. I recommend you to read the man page of each function before using it.